# How to get a static internal IP for Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, 22.04, dhcp

I'm trying to get my home server to use a static IP instead of the one from the DHCP.
I'm using Ubuntu server 22.04.

I replaced the file `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yml` with a file named `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yml` (this is the only file inside `/etc/netplan`) with this content:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.2/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

Running `sudo netplan apply`, `netplan test`, `netplan generate` works, also tried all with the `--debug` flag.

But I'm not finding a way of using that IP inside my network adapter.

Running the command `ip address show dev eno1` shows:

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether *** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s31f6
```

I restarted my system many times, and something that I noticed is that while loading Ubuntu, I get this message:

```
A start job is running for wait for network to be configured
```

That stays for 2 minutes and then it loads the login prompt.

To give context, I'm trying to do this because I want to use this computer as a DHCP server, using pi-hole. I thought of binding this IP into the DHCP itself, but as this resolution happens before the docker container is loaded, so I'm looking for a way of using a static IP without the DHCP server.

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue!

I was creating the file with `.yml` extension instead of `.yaml`. So no configs were actually being loaded.

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22268973/12145499) for difference between `.yml` and `.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be that you're providing your list of addresses in []? Mine below works:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0f0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.254/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.1.254
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.0.0.1
        search: []
    enp2s0f1:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.253/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.1.253
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.0.0.1
        search: []
  version: 2
```

Comment: Another note is I've got my network set to not have a limit on the time to configure itself, it usually takes longer than 2 minutes for me, maybe that might be why as well?

Comment: Tried with this but it's the same :(

I'm trying to get any of the netplan configs to work. I tried to get a small file with only a nameserver config and I have the same problem, so it may not be related to the config file